# Execute command after screen terminated

Tags: linux, session, gnu-screen

How can I set `screen` to execute command when specified `screen` session is will terminate?

Answer (score 1):

```
alias screen='\screen;commandhere';
```

Comment: Write a function instead of an alias then ;]

Comment: this executes the command when the instance of the `screen` process terminates, not session.